# Cost of sending XMPP messages via Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Hopefully this question is allowed over here. It does not really have to do with programming per se but with the costs associated with it.

My question is:

> "How much does sending/receiving XMPP
>   messages cost".

I can [find](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html#Billable_Quota_Unit_Cost) all the information about email etc. But I could not find information about costs sending/receiving XMPP messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#XMPP

I think it has a fixed quota - not billable.

Not sure whether that means that you just can't go over your quota. You'd probably be best asking on the GAE-Java group http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java